# Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support does not recognize steps in WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have an angular project and a cypress tests setup. I am currently using ubuntu wsl2 and the project is cloned there.

The tests work either I clone and run the project in Windows fs or in wsl. (

Right now, I am able to navigate to the steps when I open the project in vscode on windows. If I open vscode in wsl and use the project there, then the navigation does not work.

I've looked around and I did not find any setup steps specific for WSL. Does somebody knows if it is possible to make it work using wsl?

Answer (score 0):

Install this one "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevejpurves.cucumber"

Create settings.json file under ".vscode". It should include below lines.

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "local-tests/features/step_definitions/*.js",
        "local-tests/node_modules/@extlib/*.js",
        "local-tests/node_modules/extlib/subfolder/*.mjs"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "local-tests/features/*feature",
    "editor.quickSuggestions":{
        "strings": "on"
    }
}
```